# How can I debug this infinite loop of component renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have infinite loop exception when inside when the "TP" case inside my `checkCircle` function runs.
I tried to change only state without redux but it did not help.
The `checkCircle` case "TP" must update position and location of player (like a teleport).

*I removed unimportant lines of code*

## Map.js

```js
import CheckCircle from "./../../Services/checkCircle";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchPlayer } from "./../../Services/fetchPlayerAsync";
import { updatePlayerPositionAction } from "./../../Store/playerReduser";

export default function Map({ circles }) {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState([-100, 100]);
  const [previousPosition, setPreviousPosition] = useState([-100, 100]);
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState([-100, 100]);
  const [isInside, setIsInside] = useState(false);
  const [currentClassName, setCurrentClassName] = useState("");
  const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(null);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const player = useSelector((state) => state.players.players);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPlayer());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (player && player.player) {
      setLocation(player.player.location);
      setPosition(player.player.position);
      setPreviousPosition(player.player.prevPosition);
      setMapCenter(player.player.position);
    }
  }, [player]);

  const keyDownRead = (e) => {
    setKeyPressed(e.code);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownRead);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", keyDownRead);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let shortestDistance = Infinity;
    let currentisInside = false;
    let currentClassName = "";

    Object.entries(circles).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      const distance = Math.sqrt(
        (position[0] - value.center[0]) ** 2 +
          (position[1] - value.center[1]) ** 2
      );

      if (distance <= value.radius) {
        currentisInside = true;
        currentClassName = value.className;
      } else if (distance < shortestDistance) {
        shortestDistance = distance;
      }
    });

    setCurrentClassName(currentClassName);
    setIsInside(currentisInside);
  }, [position, circles]);

  return (
    <>
      {location.length > 0 ? (
        <div className="App">
          <MapContainer
            maxBounds={bounds[location]}
            dragging={true}
            boxZoom={false}
            center={mapCenter}
            minZoom={1}
            maxZoom={4}
            zoom={4}
            style={{
              height: window.innerHeight,
              width: window.innerWidth,
            }}
            crs={CRS.Simple}
            scrollWheelZoom={true}
            attributionControl={false}
          >
            <ChangeView center={position} zoom={4} />
            <TileLayer
              attribution="it’s offline"
              url={"../tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"}
            />
            {Object.entries(circles).map(([key, value]) => (
              <Circle key={key} center={value.center} radius={value.radius}>
                {isInside &&
                  value.className === currentClassName &&
                  CheckCircle(value.className, keyPressed, dispatch)}
              </Circle>
            ))}
            <Marker position={position} title="player" />
            <GetCoordinates />
            {Object.entries(borders).map(([key, value]) => (
              <Polyline key={key} positions={borders[key]} />
            ))}
          </MapContainer>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}
```

My checkCircle function

## CheckCircle.js

```js
import NPCdialog from "../Components/PlayGround/NPCdialog";
import { updatePlayerPositionLocationAction } from "../Store/playerReduser";

export default function checkCircle(circle, keyPressed, dispatch) {
  if (!circle) return;
  let event = circle.split("_")[0];
  let item1 = circle.split("_")[1];
  let item2 = circle.split("_")[2];
  switch (event) {
    case "NPC":
      if (keyPressed === "KeyE") {
        return <NPCdialog npcName={item1} />;
      }
      break;
    case "Fight":
      return null;
    case "TP":
      if(keyPressed === "KeyE") {
        const pos = JSON.parse("[" + item1 + "]");
        dispatch(updatePlayerPositionLocationAction(pos, pos, item2));
        return null;
      }
      break;
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: `inside checkCircle worked case "TP"`  What does that mean?

Comment: when the "TP" case works, or mb this problem of first useEffect

Comment: @MagCyp please don't use slangs and keep things readable. Now what is "*mb*"?

Comment: @Aleksandar mb= maybe, sorry for the slang